# How to define JUnit test time-out at runtime (i.e. without annotations)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, timeout

I want to run a unit test with a time-out that is defined at runtime. I want to define a time-out for a specific test only, not the whole class.

I saw these are the ways to set the time out:

```
@Rule
public Timeout globalTimeout = new Timeout(10000); // 10 seconds max per method tested
```

or

```
@Test(timeout=100) public void infinity() {
   while(true);
}
```

but when I run this code, no exception is thrown.
I want to identify when the test failed due to timeout.

```
public Timeout testTimeout;

private void setTestTimeOut() {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(testTimeOut)) {
        testTimeout = new Timeout(Integer.parseInt(testTimeOut));
    }
}
```

How can I catch the exception? Wrap the main method with `try-catch(InterruptException)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `TestWatcher` rule that decides, at run time, whether to apply a timeout or not:

```
@Rule
public TestWatcher watcher = new TestWatcher() {
  @Override
  public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
    // You can replace this hard-coded test name and delay with something
    // more dynamic
    if (description.getMethodName().equals("infinity")) {
      return new FailOnTimeout(base, 200);
    }

    return base;
  }
};
```

Your original approach didn't work because JUnit rules take effect before the test code begins to run, so any attempts to adjust your `Timeout` object within your test are too late.

Comment: @EladBenda Do you mean in a method annotated with `@Before`?

Comment: yes. but now I think of this: i actually want to limit timeout for only some lines in the test. Not all of it. how to do it customly?

Comment: There's one important limitation here - because this is a `TestWatcher` instead of a `Timeout`, I believe it cannot be used with `DisableOnDebug`

Answer (score -1):

The `@Test(timeout=xxx)` will not throw a `TimeoutException`, it will fail the test.

Could you specify in more detail what you would like to test?

Comment: I want to identify when the test failed due to timeout.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. If you don't have enough reputation to comment, please tackle other questions that don't require clarification.